# get window height dynamicly with jquery for image gallery

Tags: jquery

I need some help with window resize function. I have a simple lightbox image gallery, but i have an issue with the image max-height.

Now the image max-height not change if is resize the browser. I would like to image fit to the image height dinamicly.

I tried to used window resize function, but no success.

Thanks for all help.

Here is my code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var image_href = $(this).attr("href");
    var image_title = $(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    var windowHeight = $(window).height() - 100;

    var lightbox =
        '<div id="lightbox">' +
        '<div id="lightbox-in"><div id="content-lb">' +
        '<img src="' + image_href + '" />' +
        '</div></div>' +
        '</div>';
    $('body').append(lightbox);

    if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) {

        $('#lightbox-in').html('<div id="content-lb"><a class="lb-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a><img src="' + image_href + '" style="max-height:  '+ windowHeight +'px; " /></div><div class="clear"></div><span class="img-item-title">' + image_title + '</span>');

        $('#lightbox').fadeIn();
    } else {

        var lightbox =
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
            '<div id="lightbox-in"><a class="lb-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>' +
            '<div id="content-lb"><img src="' + image_href + '" style=" max-height:  '+ windowHeight +'px; " />' + 
            '</div></div>' +
            '</div>';
        $('body').append(lightbox);
    }

});

$(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function() {
    $('#lightbox').fadeOut();
    $('#lightbox').remove();
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `resize()` on the window object with jQuery.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  // window has been resized
  var height = $(window).height() - 100;
  $('#content-lb img').css('max-height', height);
});
```

I know you said you've tried `resize()` but what wasn't working with it?

Comment: Thanks its working! I'm affraid I tried it with bad syntax. Thanks for quick help! :)